# Creating a Setter for NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, setter, getter

I have to create a `NSOperationQueue` that is atomic.

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *queue;
```

I have this getter:

```
- (NSOperationQueue *)queue {
  if (_queue == nil) {
    _queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    [_queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
  }
  return _queue;
}
```

But Xcode says I have to create a setter.

How should a setter for this case of mine be? I have no idea.

Comment: I’d remove that `maxConcurrentCount` in your getter. The main queue already is a serial queue, and to call `setMaxConcurrentCount` suggests some misunderstanding about the main queue. If you create your own queue, sure, set the `maxConcurrentCount`, but not if you’re going to use the main queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two observations:

1. If you were to define your own setter, it might look like:

   ```
   - (void)setQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue {
       _queue = queue; 
   }
   ```

   Remember, if you implement both accessor methods (both the setter and getter), you’ll have to manually synthesize the ivar, e.g.

   ```
   @synthesize queue = _queue;
   ```

   in your `@implementation`, because the compiler can no longer safely assume you needed the ivar of the particular name at all.
2. You should revisit whether this should be `atomic` or `nonatomic`. Your getter is not `atomic` (nor is my example setter), so you likely just want to make this `nonatomic`. Being `atomic` "means that the synthesized accessors ensure that a value is always fully retrieved by the getter method or fully set via the setter method, even if the accessors are called simultaneously from different threads" (from [Programming with Objective-C: Properties are atomic by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW37)). You often don’t need atomic accessor methods, but if you did, you would change these implementations to synchronize accordingly (e.g., with `NSLock`, `@synchronized` directive, a serial queue, reader-writer pattern, etc.).

   Note, if you had made it `nonatomic`, that also eliminates the need for you to write a custom setter to accompany your custom getter. If you implemented your own getter for an `atomic` property, the compiler cannot synthesize a corresponding `atomic` setter because it has no way of knowing how to synchronize its setter with your getter (as there are lots of different possible synchronization mechanisms). But if you make your property `nonatomic`, where no synchronization is needed, the compiler can synthesize simple, unsynchronized setter for you, and the warning instructing you to implement a setter, too, will go away.

Answer (score 1):

First, you declared the property "queue" to be a read/write property. That doesn't make sense. You really don't want everybody to assign to "queue".

Second, you declared the property as "atomic". Either you read up on what "atomic" does, or you just believe me that it is very rare that it is useful. A hand-written getter or setter is always non-atomic. So you have a getter, which is non-atomic, and because the property itself is an atomic read/write property, you have an automatically generated setter which is atomic. You can't combine a non-atomic getter with an atomic setter or vice versa.

How to solve: Change the property to nonatomic and readonly. One side effect is that you lose the _queue backing variable (you don't get a backing variable if all required accessors are implemented), so you will have to declare _queue yourself.

Comment: "A hand-written getter or setter is always non-atomic", hmmm... I didn't know all atomic code was automatically (or foot?) written ;-)